# Is any of the sets a subset of a union of other sets?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, inequality

I have eleven sets, all of them are subsets of  $X:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in[-1,1]^4: a\le b,\text{ and } c\le d\}$:
$$\begin{align*}
A_1&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X: b\ge 0,\  c\le a+b+d\}\\
A_2&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X: b\ge 0,\  d\ge 0\}\\
A_3&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X:  b\ge 0,\  a+b+2d\ge 0\}\\
A_4&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X:  d\ge 0,\  a\le b+c+d\}\\
A_5&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X:  d\ge 0,\  2b+c+d\ge 0\}\\
A_6&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X: a\le b+c+d,\  c\le a+b+d\}\\
A_7&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X:  a\le b+c+d,\  a+b+2d\ge 0\}\\
A_8&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X:  2b+c+d\ge 0,\  c\le a+b+d\}\\
A_9&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X:  2b+c+d\ge 0,\  a+b+2d\ge 0,\  c\le 2b+d\}\\
A_{10}&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X:  2b+c+d\ge 0,\  a+b+2d\ge 0,\  a\le b+2d\}\\
A_{11}&:=\{(a,b,c,d)\in X :  2b+c+d\ge 0,\  a+b+2d\ge 0,\  b+d\ge 0\}.
\end{align*}$$
My question is: Are these sets independent, i.e. is any of the sets a subset of a union of other sets?

Comment: Where did this arise?

Comment: It is out of my attempt to find shortest path on the unit sphere of  the sup norm.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this efficiently, but +1 for an interesting algorithmic problem.

Comment: Is the condition on $X$ the conjunction of two conditions, $a\leq b$ and $c\leq d$, or was it the condition that both $b$ and $c$ lie between $a$ and $d$? The notation "$a\leq b,c\leq d$" is ambiguous.

Comment: Your edit is correct.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: If you put (at)someuser at the start of a comment that user will get a ping when you comment.  In this case Arturo Magidin might not see it.  Unfortunately (IMHO) you can only ping one user this way.  I had to make it (at) instead of the symbol because I got a warning about exactly the behavior I was complaining about.

Comment: You have 36 sets in $X$, 6 choices for each pair $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ So calculate all the A's:  how many are left?  Probably not many.  A little thought looking at them may yield enlightenment.

Comment: @Ross. Don't know which 6 choices you mean. Perhaps you have another proof better than my case by case proof below?

Comment: @TCL:  I was taking the elements to be integers, so (a,b) could be (-1,-1), (-1,0), etc up to (1,1).  I see now that you were thinking reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Every $A_i$ is a subset of $A_1\cup A_4$.

For $A_2$: We have $b+d\ge 0$. Since either $c\le a$ or $a\le c$, we have either $c\le a+b+d$ or $a\le b+c+d$, proving that $A_2\subset A_1\cup A_4$.

For $A_3$: If $d\ge 0$, then the point is in $A_2$ which is a subset of $A_1\cup A_4$. If $d\le 0$ then $-d\ge c$ since $c\le d\le 0$. So $a+b+d\ge -d\ge c$, proving that the point is in $A_1$.

Similar arguments apply to other $A_i$'s.